# Old style JOIN (ANSI JOINs) syntax is not allowed. Split DATE

Tags: marketing-cloud, date, automationstudio, sql

I'm using a simple SQL query to get DAY, MONTH, YEAR out of a Date field (BIRTH_DATE) in Automation Studio (of marketing cloud).

```
SELECT 
  CUST_CODE
, EXCLUDED_FROM_NPS
, BIRTH_DATE
, DATEPART(DD,BIRTH_DATE) AS DAY_DOB
, DATEPART(MM,BIRTH_DATE) AS MONTH_DOB
, DATEPART(YYYY,BIRTH_DATE) AS YEAR_DOB
FROM Import_Customer_TH
```

When I validate the syntax, it gives the error

> An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Old style
>   JOIN (ANSI JOINs) syntax is not allowed. Please use standard syntax.
>   _NPS, is not a known data extension or system data view. You can only query existing data extensions or system data views

I don't have any Joins in the query.
I tried this version too, but same error

```
 SELECT 
  CUST_CODE
, EXCLUDED_FROM_NPS
, BIRTH_DATE
, DAY(BIRTH_DATE) AS DAY_DOB
, MONTH(BIRTH_DATE) AS MONTH_DOB
, YEAR(BIRTH_DATE) AS YEAR_DOB
FROM Import_Customer_TH
```

Comment: Have you tried rename EXCLUDED_FROM_NPS column? the error looks like it confused Excluded_From_NPS  with TSQL "From _NPS".

Comment: ahhhh!! interesting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SQL parser in SFMC is really dumb sometimes.

I'd recommend something like what [@Bo Hu](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/28187/bo-hu) suggested, but just add brackets around it:

```
SELECT 
  CUST_CODE
, [EXCLUDED_FROM_NPS]
, BIRTH_DATE
, DATEPART(DD,BIRTH_DATE) AS DAY_DOB
, DATEPART(MM,BIRTH_DATE) AS MONTH_DOB
, DATEPART(YYYY,BIRTH_DATE) AS YEAR_DOB
FROM Import_Customer_TH
```

I did a quick test and this appears to work.

Comment: I was just getting this error "The __c table has been deleted and can no longer be used in a query." and adding the brackets fixed it. Thanks!